# 403 Forbidden Wordpress Database Results

Tags: php, wpdb

I have a website, hosted on Wordpress.

I have created a custom table within the WPDB, with ARI Adminer,  called 'people'.
I have entered some entries for testing.

I have created a test page with the following code;

```
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 $roster = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM people"));
 foreach ($roster as $people) {
   $peoplesurname = $people->Surname;
 }
?>
```

When I preview the page, I get:

> 403 Forbidden
>   Permission denied. Our sentries tell us that you should not be here.

I am listed as an administrator, however I did not setup/install anything, I was added after setup.

I am assuming that it is an access issue to the WPDB?

Is there anywhere on the front end or in the code that I need to update to get access to the DB?

Thanks

Comment: How did you create the test page? Where did you put the code?

Comment: Just via the Add Pages menu, in the code editor tab. Historically I would create a .php page, but because the page is hosted on Wordpress, I can't add the pages via ftp.

Comment: You can't use PHP in the code editor for pages, unless you're using a plugin. Anyway, "Our sentries tell us that you should not be here" is not an error message from WordPress. Either it's from your host, in which case you'll need to speak with them, or you're using some sort of plugin that controls access to pages.

Comment: ok thanks Jacob. We have the PHP Snippets plugin installed, but I had read that you should just be able to enter the code as above as it was talking directly to the local db. I'll take a look at what plugins we're using, to see what I can see.